# Replacement for rcconf for Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04

In Ubuntu 10.04, rcconf no longer works for managing services.

Any suggested replacement?

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu has been migrating their sys-V init scripts to upstart. The tool to manage upstart process is initctl; check its man page. You can call directly its aliases:

```
/sbin/start
/sbin/status
/sbin/reload
/sbin/stop
/sbin/restart
```

For example:

```
start apache2
stop apache2
reload apache2
```

Comment: I am looking for tool to manage the services' runlevel, not how to start/stop the service.

Comment: http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/

Answer (score 0):

The `rcconf` package is [still available](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/rcconf) for Lucid (10.04). You should be able to install it like normal (`sudo aptitude/apt-get install rcconf`), assuming that you have the universe repositories enabled in your `/etc/apt/sources.list`. This tool should still work for managing services (or, at least, it does for me).

Comment: rcconf might not work if the script is managed by upstart

Answer (score 0):

[jobs-admin](https://launchpad.net/jobsadmin) (and its backend service, jobs-service) is the tool for configuring Upstart scripts.  It's not available for 10.04 though. You need 10.10.

Additionally, Ubuntu has no distinction between runlevels other than 0 (halt), 1 (single), and 6 (reboot).  Like Debian, it does the same thing for 2-5.

You can change Upstart script dependencies (start-on *event*, stop-on *event*, etc) in the service's config file, located at /etc/init/*service*.conf